# How to run a playbook conditionally if any of a property is True

Tags: ansible, jinja2, templating

I have the following variable

```
stack:
    blackbox:
      enabled: false
      version: master
      config_path: /srv/blackbox/blackbox.yml

    prometheus:
      enabled: false
      hostname: prometheus.uttnetgroup.fr
        
    node_exporter:
      enabled: false
      hostname: node_exporter.uttnetgroup.fr
```

I would like run my playbook if any of the property `enabled` is True.

For now, I have

```
- name: Install Docker services
  debug:
    msg: "Awesome"
  when: "True in '{{ stack | json_query('*.*.enabled') }}')"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: stack
    index_var: stack_name
```

But I it doesn't work and I don't know if I still should dig in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use *assert* and [test list values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-if-a-list-value-is-true). For example

```yaml
    - assert:
        that: stack|json_query('*.enabled') is any
        fail_msg: None of the properties is True
```